# Unable to access Ubuntu desktop after successful boot

Tags: boot

After a BIOS update I am facing an issue where Ubuntu appears to boot successfully, displaying messages like "mounted", "reached", "created" and "starting", but I am unable to access the desktop or proceed further. I have not encountered any specific error messages during the boot process.

[image]